# Criar um balão de pensamentos em css

Tags: html, css

```css
.balloon-box {
    width: 281px;
    height: 53px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 26.5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.balloon-box::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon-box balloon-circle">
    <p class="balloon-text">I can help marketing strategy</p>
</div>
```

Ola, Alguem poderia me ajudar a criar esse balão igual a imagem, só que em css?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já que vc está usando um `pseudo::after`, use um `::before` para fazer a outra bolinha

A sombra que é o pulo do gato, para fazer a forma mais prática que eu encontrei foi usando um `filter: drop-shadow`, pois ele coloca a sombra no "conteúdo" e não exatamente no limite do `box-model` como seria o caso do `box-shadow`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***OBS:*** Os filtros tem um excelente suporte, mas não funciona no IE (quem liga rss) https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}
.balloon-box {
  width: 281px;
  height: 53px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 26.5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.balloon-box::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  right: 30px;
}
.balloon-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: -21px;
}
.balloon-box {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon-box balloon-circle">
    <p class="balloon-text">I can help marketing strategy</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara valeu mano, eu estava andando em círculos aqui, valeu msm.

Comment: @Gabriel sem problemas meu caro esse tipo de sombreamento eh bem chato quando não se sabe a técnica

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>p</title>

<style>

body {
 background-color: pink;
}

div {
 width: 400px;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: ;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15pt;
 line-height: 65px;
}

.balloon-text {
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p#max {
 position: absolute;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 top: 45px;
 left: 320px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

p#min {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 90px;
 left: 370px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 background-color: #ffffff; 
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
 <div class="balloon">
  <p class="balloon-text">I can help marketing strategy</p>
  <p id="max"></p>
  <p id="min"></p>
 </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ficou legal. Só faltou o sombreado.